# Cement pool overhang patch or replace

Tags: pool, cement, patch

I have a pool with an overhanging cement edge that crumbled away. I have one contractor that said we should replace it and another that said we should just patch it. Here are some pictures of it. Which option should I take?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the problem that caused this was the rebar was two close to the edge. If you patch it will be in the same place. But would be less noticeable than a section that has been replaced.

Comment: @EdBeal would removing the rebar help the repair last or would that hurt the adhesion too much?

Comment: I would worry about totally removing it but would grind it down to get rid of the heavy rust and reduce the diameter

Comment: No way I would replace it because what would be done differently where it did not fail the exact same way?

Comment: @EdBeal If you look closely at the first picture, it looks like the original installer cut completely through the rebar when they did the expansion joint with a saw, so there is some structural rigidity to it, but not as much as a full bar. At most I would take a wire brush to it, I wouldn't grind it, just to get the loose surface rust off.

Comment: The plan so far is to cut out the damaged area, get rid of the rebar, and replace it with some heavy duty fiberglass mesh/net to support the cement patching.

Answer (score 1):

I would chip away everything that is crumbling and patch it. Make sure that you get all the cracks knocked out and patch out from there.

Chances are that the patch won't match the surrounding cement but if you think about it, you'll spend maybe $20 in patch materials (more if you need the trowel tools) and if it fails after a year you are out $20 and no harm done. If it holds, great, but at least you have a year (or more) to save for a larger fix in the future.

As far as leaving the rebar there or removing it, you should be able to leave it there with the proper patch cement. They usually have bonding chemicals in the cement and can bond to the rebar without using a chemical bonding agent. You may need to make a form for the underside or just mix the cement a little dry. Forms can easily be made from foam insulation (the pink sheets) available at any hardware store.

One more thing, when you patch, don't fill the expansion joints with cement, use duct-tape or weather stripping to keep the cement out of the expansion joint.